# Pub/static js path wrong in magento2 after install ebizmarts mage monkey plugin

Tags: frontend, static-content, magento2.1.6

Recently i have tried to install Ebizmarts_MageMonkey plugin in magento2. After install frontend not working properly. Got an error like some js missing.

> 404 not found error
>   http://test.com/pub/static/frontend/xxx/xxx/en_US/cookiejs.js

But that cookiejs.js exist under **pub/static/frontend/xxx/xxx/en_US/js** folder

Called that file path from wrong folder. If i installed that plugin in fresh  magento2 project, That plugin was working fine. Can't able to find the reason why is it call that js file from wrong folder path.

Please let me know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Please deploy static content as follows and try again.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static/
```

You need to run this command from Magento 2 root directory.

Comment: Tried this already. But its too not working.

Comment: First remove pub/static directory and deploy again

Comment: Checked by removing pub/static folder & deploy. Not working..